# Show that if $x$ has a terminating decimal expansion then $x=p/q$ for integers $p,q$ where the only prime factors of q are 2's and 5's.

Tags: proof-writing, rational-numbers

I've proven the converse statement but don't know where to start for this statement. Would you suggest doing a proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

If $x=0.a_1a_2\ldots a_k$, then 
\begin{align*}
x& =0.a_1a_2\ldots a_k\\
& =\frac{a_1a_2\ldots a_k}{10^k}
\end{align*}

The denominator has only possible prime factors as $2$ and $5$.